# Handling blanks and dealing with sums in pivots with google sheets query

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, pivot, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to cope with blanks and a total row in google sheets.  This is my ridiculous solution.  I'm sure, someone has a much better solution

```
={query({query (query(vd!A:G,"select C,sum(G) where F = 'fm' or F = 'fma' group by C pivot F order by C"),"select Col1"),arrayformula(query (N(query(vd!A:G,"select C,sum(G) where F = 'fm' or F = 'fma' group by C pivot F order by C")),"select Col2, Col3"))},"select Col1,Col2,Col3, Col3-Col2 where Col2-Col3 > 50000 or Col2-Col3 < -50000 label Col1 'Program', Col2 'Forecast', Col3 'Actuals', Col3-Col2 'Variance'");{"Total",index(query({query (query(vd!A:G,"select C,sum(G) where F = 'fm' or F = 'fma' group by C pivot F order by C"),"select Col1"),arrayformula(query (N(query(vd!A:G,"select C,sum(G) where F = 'fm' or F = 'fma' group by C pivot F order by C")),"select Col2, Col3"))},"select sum(Col2),sum(Col3), sum(Col3)-sum(Col2) where Col2-Col3 > 50000 or Col2-Col3 < -50000"),2)}}
```

I made a view of the sheet this is on for easier handling.  Is there an easy way to anonoymize data?

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YA7xgOtOXKhtOos6acaS40BMxBcAE8g9VMkdUaBGrMg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: No way to anoyingmouse your data, what you can do to avoid sharing data you don't want to share is: Make a copy of the sheet with some sample dummy data, after all  what the community needs in order to answer is generic or sample data, and the minimal of it.

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({"Program", "Forecast", "Actuals", "Variance"; 
 QUERY(QUERY({INDEX(QUERY(vd!A:G,
 "select C,sum(G) 
  where F matches 'fma|fm'
  group by C 
  pivot F 
  order by C"),, 1), 
 QUERY(N(QUERY(vd!A:G, 
 "select C,sum(G) 
  where F matches 'fma|fm'
  group by C 
  pivot F 
  order by C")), 
 "select Col2,Col3")},
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col3-Col2 
  where Col2-Col3 >  50000 
     or Col2-Col3 < -50000", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0); 
 "Total", QUERY(QUERY(QUERY(QUERY({INDEX(QUERY(vd!A:G,
 "select C,sum(G) 
  where F matches 'fma|fm'
  group by C 
  pivot F 
  order by C"),, 1), 
 QUERY(N(QUERY(vd!A:G, 
 "select C,sum(G) 
  where F matches 'fma|fm'
  group by C 
  pivot F 
  order by C")), 
 "select Col2,Col3")},
 "select Col2,Col3,Col3-Col2 
  where Col2-Col3 >  50000 
     or Col2-Col3 < -50000", 0), 
 "offset 1", 0), 
 "select sum(Col1),sum(Col2),sum(Col3)"), 
 "offset 1", 0)})
```

[image]